# Accordion style QuickLaunch in SharePoint 2010

Tags: asp.net, quick-launch

I need help in entering the selectors in Sharepoint 2010 for a biz website in the left menu under the navigation:

Here is my code for QuickLaunchMenu in Sharepoint for my Web part Accordion menu:

```
  <Sharepoint:SPNavigationManager

id="QuickLaunchNavigationManager"

runat="server"

QuickLaunchControlId="QuickLaunchMenu"

ContainedControl="QuickLaunch"

EnableViewState="false"

CssClass="ms-quicklaunch-navmgr">

<div>

<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="QuickLaunchDataSource">

<Template_Controls>


<asp:SiteMapDataSource SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider" ShowStartingNode="False" id="QuickLaunchSiteMap" StartingNodeUrl="sid:1025" runat="server" />

</Template_Controls>

</SharePoint:DelegateControl>

<SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="3" runat="server">

<ContentTemplate>

<SharePoint:AspMenu id="QuickLaunchMenu" runat="server" DataSourceId="QuickLaunchSiteMap" Orientation="Vertical" StaticDisplayLevels="2" ItemWrap="true" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0" StaticSubMenuIndent="0" SkipLinkText="" CssClass="s4-die">

<LevelMenuItemStyles>

<asp:menuitemstyle CssClass="table.ms-navheader" />

<asp:menuitemstyle CssClass="ms-navitem" />

</LevelMenuItemStyles>

<LevelSubMenuStyles>

<asp:submenustyle CssClass="ms-navSubMenu1" />

<asp:submenustyle CssClass="table.ms-navSubMenu2" />

</LevelSubMenuStyles>

<LevelSelectedStyles>

<asp:menuitemstyle CssClass="ms-selectednavheader" />

<asp:menuitemstyle CssClass="a.ms-selectednav" />

</LevelSelectedStyles>

</SharePoint:AspMenu>

</ContentTemplate>

</SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>

<SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server">

<ContentTemplate>

<SharePoint:AspMenu id="V4QuickLaunchMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DataSourceId="QuickLaunchSiteMap" UseSimpleRendering="true" UseSeparateCss="false" Orientation="Vertical" StaticDisplayLevels="2" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0" SkipLinkText="" CssClass="s4-ql" />

</ContentTemplate>

</SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>

</div>

</Sharepoint:SPNavigationManager>
```

With the Accordion Style in this accordion.js file show in this link:
http://www.deviantpoint.com/post/2009/01/16/Creating-an-accordion-style-SharePoint-Quick-Launch-menu-with-jQuery.aspx

How can I match this to make my QuickLaunch render in Sharepoint 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Link in your question is refering MOSS 2007. It can be ported Sharepoint 2010, check link below:

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Accordion-Style-Quick-Launch-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx